# How to calculate derivative of integral with variable in both limit and integral?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let $f(x,y)$ be some function of two variables. How do we calculate the derivative of $$\int_{g(y)}^{h(y)}  f(x,y) dx$$

with respect to $y$? Is there a general rule?

Comment: Please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is and it is called "Leibniz's rule for differentiation under the integral sign".
And it reads
$$
\frac{d}{dy}\left(\int\limits_{g(y)}^{h(y)}f(x,y)dx\right) = f(h(y),y)\frac{dh}{dy}(y) - f(g(y),y)\frac{dg}{dy}(y)+ \int\limits_{g(y)}^{h(y)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)dx
$$
See [this paper here](http://sgpwe.izt.uam.mx/files/users/uami/jdf/proyectos/Derivar_inetegral.pdf) or Spivak's Caulculus book.